# How to check entered url is indexing on google or not using php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a script that should check all indexed pages from Google. But it will not give proper output.

```
<?php
function indexed($url) {
    $url = 'http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:' . urlencode($url);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Chrome 10');

    if (!curl_exec($ch)) {
        // var_dump('failed');
        return false;
    }

    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      //var_dump($code);
    return $code == '200';
}
echo indexed('http://www.berlin-info.de/de/tourist-info/urlaub-in-kanada');

?>
```

Comment: This is a broad topic and needs to be studied. You just can't find indexed pages like this. You have to crawl ..

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI, Then suggest me how can i find indexed pages?

Comment: Crawl  you have to crawl each google page

Answer (score 1):

I use this code and work for me.

```
$url = 'example.com';
if (strstr(file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/search?q=site:$url"), 'did not match any documents')) {
 
  $result = false;
}
else {
   $result = true;
}
print $result;
```